# Howto generate code for Typescript-Angular2 with Swagger Codegen which contains validation information

Tags: swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I use swagger-codegen version 2.2.3 to generate an API for typescript-angular2 - so far everything works great.

The command I use is:

> java -jar ./swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.3.jar generate -i http://example.ch/swagger/docs/v1 -l typescript-angular2 -o ./src/api -DsupportES6=true -DmodelPropertyNaming=original

The Swagger JSON file contains as well additional information. e.g. minLength, maxLength of a string, see following picture.

[image]

I cannot find this information (minLength,maxLength) in the generated code.

Does swagger-coden for typescript-angular2 not support this or do is miss something?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the community can help you out.

Comment: Thanks @wing328 for the response, I will open one.

Comment: Issue on Githubg: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6410